# delete[] and delete seems to behave alike

Tags: c++

here if I use `delete` or `delete[]` the output is still 70. Can I know why?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* c = new int[100];
    for(int i=0; i<98; i++)
    {
        c[i] = i;
    }

    cout<<c[70]<<endl;
    delete[] c;
      or
    delete c;
    cout<<c[70]<<endl; //outputs 70 even after delete[] or delete
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete` is not supposed to clear the memory contents

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: By chance you are referring to the old memory before the OS has happened to reclaim or reuse it. It is not guaranteed to work and should be considered a bug in your code.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `new` and `delete` anyway. They almost always lead to bugs. This is C++, not Java, so we don't need to explicitly use the heap. Just do `int c[100]` instead of `new`, then you don't need to delete

Comment: You could also use a `std::vector<int> c(100);`

Comment: In modern clean C++ application code (evolution completed by C++14 and `make_unique`), if you use any of `new`, `delete`, raw pointers or even (in most cases) C style arrays, you are doing something wrong. Use C++ (STL or other) containers, values with move semantics when practical, and smart pointers like `unique_ptr` for heap allocations. It might be better to learn these first, and leave more primitive stuff for later (maybe after learning the implementation of library-like template classes).

Comment: @hyde I would even go so far and argue that learning to deal with `new` and `delete` is only useful if you have to maintain legacy code bases. There is absolutely no need to learn about them otherwise, *not even late*; you would just be burning precious brain cycles for zero benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `new` will just allocate some memory to your program and return a pointer pointing at the said memory address, reserving as much memory as needed for the datatype. When you use `delete` later, it "frees" the memory, but doesn't delete it's content. If you had an `int` with the value 70 stored at that address, it will still contain 70, until another application wants some memory, gets said address and puts another value in there.

If you use `new` to allocate memory for an array, you will reserve following blocks of memory until there are enough blocks for your specified array length.

Let's say you do the following:

```
int main() {
    int* array = new int[10]; // array now points to the first block of the allocated memory
    delete array;             // since array points to the first block of the array, it will only free that block, but nothing else, causing a memory leak
    delete[] array;           // will free all memory allocated by the previous new

    // Note that you should never free allocated memory twice, like in this code sample. Using delete on already freed memory is undefined behaviour!

]
```

Always use `delete` for single variables and `delete[]` for arrays.

A demonstration of your problem:

```
int main() {
    int* c = new int[10];  // We allocate memory for an array of 10 ints
    c[0] = 1;              // We set the value of the first int inside the array to 1
    delete[] c;
    /* 
     * We free the previously allocated memory.
     * Note that this does not delete the CONTENT of the memory!
     * c does still point towards the first block of the array!
     */

    std::cout << c[0];
    /* 
     * Firstly, this is undefined behaviour (Accessing deallocated memory).
     * However, this will output 1,
     * unless some other process allocated the memory at the address
     * and filled it with another value already. (Very unlikely)
     */
    return 0;

}
```

If you want to delete / overwrite the *content* of the deleted memory, you can use [`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset).

Example:

```
#include <cstring>
int main() {
    std::size_t length = 10;
    int* c = new int[length];
    c[0] = 1;
    std::cout << c[0] << std::endl; // Will output 1
    std::memset( c, 0, length );    // Fill the memory with 0 bytes
    delete[] c;                     // Now we free the array's memory
    std::cout << c[0] << std::endl; // Will output 0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Accessing deleted memory is undefined behavior. Deleting with the wrong `delete` is also UB. Any further discussion is pointless in the sense that you cannot reliably expect *any* outcome.

In many cases, UB will just do the *"correct"*  thing, but you need to be aware that this is completely "by chance"  and could change with another compiler, another version of the same compiler, the weather... To get correct code, you need to avoid *all* cases of UB, even those that seemingly work.

Comment: While the essence of this answer is 100% correct, please try to make it friendlier.

Comment: @TimothyShields What do you suggest? Replacing my last sentence with the old "it can order a pizza" example? Feel free to do this in an edit if you feel it improves the answer.

Comment: @hyde you might get a warning `warning: deleting array 'p'`, but as we know from reading questions on this site, people *don't* use warnings.

Comment: Yeah, better, though I'd still still expand on just why `delete` vs `delete[]` is important. People are bad at remembering or obeying instructions "it us UB, just don't do it", and much better at remembering "the difference is this and this" and obeying "use the right one or UB will bite you".

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed its undefined behaviour and anything can happen.
These can be easily caught with the help of tools like valgrind.